# I need to display summary report in Django admin site. How do I count number of users where gender status is 0 or 1

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I am overriding change_list.html and here is what I have in my admin.py file.

```
class MyHelperGenderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'admin/helper_chart_change_list.html'
    date_hierarchy = 'created_at'
    list_filter = ('gender', 'created_at')

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        response = super().changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context, )
        try:
            qs = response.context_data['cl'].queryset
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            return response

        metrics = {
            'male': Count('gender', gender=1),
            'female': Count('gender', gender=0),
            'total_helpers': Count('id')
        }

        response.context_data['helper'] = list(
            qs.values('gender').annotate(**metrics).order_by('-male')
        )
        return response

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False


admin.site.register(MyHelperChart, MyHelperGenderAdmin)
```

In my metrics dictionary, i need a way to count where gender is either 0 or 1. Currently, The count method count everything regards of the gender status.

Here is my model:

```
class Helper(auth.models.User):
    MALE = 1
    FEMALE = 0

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (MALE, 'Male'),
        (FEMALE, 'Female')
    )
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                                 message=
                                 "Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed."
                                 )
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=15, blank=True, unique=True, null=True)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=MALE, null=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    facebook_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    google_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    lng = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    lat = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=upload_location,
        null=True, blank=True,
        width_field="width_field",
        height_field="height_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Helpers"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


class MyHelperChart(Helper):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = 'Helper Gender Summmary'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Helpers Gender Summaries'
```

I have created a proxy model which I will be using in my Django admin in order to display summary of data and a chart.

Comment: can you add your models ?

Comment: Hello, scharette, I have added my model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is add a case to both the male and female metrics. Here's an example, and then you can do the same for female = 0:

```js
from django.db.models import Case, When, IntegerField

class MyHelperGenderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

...

metrics = {
   ...
   'male': Count(Case(
                When(gender = 1, then = 1),
                output_field = IntegerField())),
   ...
   }
```